# Hamburger Bootstrap Menu in Both Desktop and Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a situation where I would like to display the Hamburger Menu on Both Desktop and Mobile, the following code works well on mobile but on desktop, it shows full navigation, in desktop as well I would like to show the **same** hamburger menu and on the right of the screen on desktop, is that possible?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".navbar-toggler").click(function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <title>Responsive Header</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
<script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `navbar-expand-md`

Change

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
```

to

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
```

Comment: Works, great but one issue. I do not want that "Home" to be displayed in desktop as well, so only toggle menu, is that possible?

Comment: simply remove `<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>` from your code

Comment: thanks much that helped. and I accepted answer.. one last question. the toggle menu right now is displayed on the left of the screen, how do you display it on the right

Comment: add this  `<span></span>` in the place you removed the anchor tag

Comment: <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

span is already there

Comment: add it right after `<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">`

Comment: you can have multiple spans, it doesn't matter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251788/discussion-between-otejiri-and-user580950).